# MySQL Select all distinct ID where all rows match the where close

Tags: mysql, join

My data table structure (I will keep it as simple as possible) :

```
ID      col1    col2
1       1       1
1       0       1
1       1       1
2       1       1
2       0       1
3       1       1
3       1       1
```

I need to have every ID where all entries of that given ID, col1 = 1 and col2 = 1.

So in this case, only the ID 3 should be given, because all of it's entries that have col1=1 also have col2=1.

I've tried numbers of joins, tried to use something like selecting the min(col2) where col1=1 joining the same table on itself on a.ID = b.ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(col1 = 0) = 0
and sum(col2 = 0) = 0
```

Comment: This request as it is didn't work but I managed to make it work like this :
"select ID from table group by ID having  sum(col1 = 1) = sum(col2 = 1)". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(col1) = COUNT(id)
  AND SUM(col2) = COUNT(id)
```